# Would I be violating the patent if I produced a similar product with completely different methods and had different intentions for product?

Tags: software, claims

In reference to the patent: [US7123424](https://www.google.com/patents/US7123424)

I would like to make a similar product, but I do not know if I am violating their patent.  It is very broad and obviously trying to protect it from being recreated. Their patent discusses reproduction for HD, DVD, cd, ETC. My priority would be to create a recording device and transmit signal via bluetooth or some other medium to be used for reproduction for teaching and learning methods, both in education, medical, and entertainment purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Determining infringement is best done with the assistance of a trusted patent attorney. This analysis comprises comparing the claims of the issued patent in question to the product and/or activities being performed.

It's impossible to say whether there might be infringement without knowing the details of what you are/would be doing and then making a comparison to the claims of this patent. Plus, such an analysis is out of the scope of what is possible in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

A patent is said to be infringed when a product/process violates the rights granted to a patentee.

To determine infringement of a patent by a product/process, one has to go through a section of a patent document called the claims. The claims section of a patent document describes in detail, the scope of protection granted to a patent.

The claims have to be analyzed in detail to find out if a product/process infringes upon the rights of a patentee. Depending on the nature of the claim, the claim would include a number of elements or process steps. Subsequently the scope of each of the elements/process steps has to be determined. Thereafter, your product/process has to be compared with the elements/process steps of the claim. The above comparison helps you determine whether the claimed elements/steps exist in your product/process.

A claim is said to be infringed if all the elements of the claim exists in your product. Similarly, a claim that includes process steps is said to be infringed, if all the process steps are present in the process that you intend to follow. In other words, if all the elements in the claims of the patent map on to the features of your product, your product is infringing upon the patent rights of the patentee.

It should be noted that, if your product does not have at least one essential element of the claim and does not fall under obvious replacements, then your product does not infringe upon the patent rights of the patentee.